# If $(x_n)$ is bounded and $x_{n+m}-x_n\to 0$ for all $m$ when $n\to \infty $ does $(x_n)$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ s.t. for all $m\in\mathbb N$, $$\lim_{n\to \infty }x_{n+m}-x_n=0.$$
Does $(x_n)$ converges ? I think it's not true, but I can't find a counter example. I did it when $m=1$ or $m=2$, but for all $m$ looks more complicated.

May be is true, and I tired as follow : Since $(x_n)$ converges, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that converges. Let denote $x$ its limit. Then $$|x_{k}-x_{n_k}|\leq |x_{n_k}-x|+|x_k-x_{n_k}|.$$
Now, is there any reason for $|x_{n_k}-x_k|\to 0$ when $k\to \infty $ ?

Comment: @Pspl, that's wrong. What you mean is that a sequence converges if this limit holds uniformly in $m$

Comment: Yeah, if there's convergence it's not obvious.  A counterexample seems possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is incorrect, as can be seen by letting $x_n = \sin \sqrt{n}$ for example. Here $x_{n+m} - x_n = \sin(\sqrt{n + m})- \sin \sqrt{n}$, which is bounded in absolute value by ${m \over 2\sqrt{n}}$ by the mean value theorem. Hence the difference $x_{n+m} - x_n$ converges to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. However, the oscillatory nature of the sine function ensures that $x_n$ does not converge to zero, or any other value.

Comment: The statement was : does it converges ? Not "prove it converges". But thanks for the counter example :)

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed false. As a counterexample, you can take

\begin{align*}
x_n =& \ln(n) - \lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor \text{ if } \ln(n) \in [2k,2k+1), k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
x_n =& 1- (\ln(n) - \lfloor \ln(n) \rfloor) \text{ if } \ln(n) \in [2k-1,2k), k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
 as a counterexample

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sequence formed by letting
$$
x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}
$$
is a counterexample.

Comment: He also demanded the sequence to be bounded